# Synchronize production and development servers

Tags: git, web-services, deployment, synchronization, remote-server

I am relatively new with web development. I've been doing it by myself for several years, but now I do it at work, so I need to find professional solutions for something as trivial as synchronization.

I have a development server, staging server, and then off course there is the production server. The thing is that when upgrading the production server, they use to re-upload all files manually, and this takes a lot of time.

I use git as version control, and I think that configuring the development machine (or stage) as git server should be enough if I can get ssh access to the production server and  then use git to do the synchronization.

I know about the Dreamweaver feature, but it is so slow and uploads the files by ftp one by one, so I prefer something better than this.

But my certain question, is if there is any other solution more specific for this task, or what the ways that professional people use to do this work.

Thank you everybody for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a deployment tool like Puppet or Chef, but I know very little about this.

You can package the deployment as something appropriate (tar/zip/jar/war/deb/rpm) and have a script to go grab it from a "deployment repository" on another server, which you - or your build scripts - dump the deployment files onto.

You can do continuous deployment.

There are lots of options.

Comment: thank you! I was looking for something like puppet, or the keywords "deployment tool". I thing with that I will be able to get what I need.